# python google calendar api 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

So I am trying to access google calendar with python, and have run into error. here is my code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
CLIENT_SECRET = r'C:\Users\Kids\Desktop\client_secret.json'

store = file.Storage(r'C:\Users\Kids\Desktop\storage.json')
creds = store.get()

GCAL = build('calendar','v3',http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Kids/redsox.py", line 17, in <module>
GCAL = build('calendar','v3',http=creds.authorize(Http()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

Comment: What is returned from store.get()?

Comment: I suggest testing [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) for this situation as it includes authorization sample and basic calendar API calls. Also related to [github post](https://github.com/home-assistant/home-assistant/issues/11995).

Comment: So I think the problem has to do with the store.get() not actually doing anything. I have the storage.json in my desktop on my computer, and its empty. It seems like it supposed to be created by the computer, but that wasnt working.

Comment: even i am facing the same issue from a couple days, i can get the oauth2client.file.Storage object but when i pass to .get() , it returns none